# How to configure vscode to autocomplete css frameworks like bulma

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, bulma

When I using bulma in VSCode, it did't give any suggestion(autocomplete) of the bulma class name. I find it hard to remember some bulma class name when I am still a newbie of it.

I'm using Vue-CLI 3, and import bulma css framework like the flow code in `main.js`:

```
import 'bulma/css/bulma.min.css'
```

So, How to configure the VSCode to give smart suggestion of class names (or any other CSS frameworks like Bootstrap) ?

Thanks.

Comment: Something like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fiazluthfi.bulma-snippets might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need IntelliSense, here's a link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense

Comment: I have installed the IntelliSense extension. But it seems not working. Do I have to configure?

Comment: Here's a link on how to configure, customize and a FAQ for IntelliSense: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense

I don't know exactly what parts you need but I'm sure that you'll find it here, it's very well documented. I also found other Bulma extensions (not IntelliSense) on the Visual Code Marketplace, maybe try some out.